# How to disable and revoke rights for a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I used a Facebook app but I want to remove it completely. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Facebook. Click on `"Account"`
   then click `"Privacy Settings"`.
2. Look at the bottom left of the page,
   click `"Edit your settings"` under
   `Apps and Websites`.
3. Click on `"Edit Settings"`
   immediately to the right of the
   `"Apps You Use"` section.
4. Click `"Edit settings"` to change
   application settings, or click the
   `"X"` to remove the app.