# How can I revoke rights for all Facebook applications?

Tags: facebook

[I know I can disable and revoke rights for specific application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12000/how-to-disable-and-revoke-rights-for-a-facebook-application), but I have so many applications that will take so much time to remove them all.

Is there a way that I can revoke all these applications together and more easier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to Facebook.
2. Click on **Account** then click **Privacy Settings**.
3. Look at the bottom left of the page, click **Edit your settings** under *Apps and Websites*.
4. Click on **Turn off all platform apps**.[image]

From the [main page](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=211829542181913).

**Note from the Facebook Help:**

> Note that you may lose all existing Platform information and settings you've saved and friends won't be able to interact with you using any applications or websites, and this cannot be recovered.

Comment: 5. Click **Select all**.  6. Click on **Turn Off Platform**.

Comment: Well, not really a solution , cause I still need some applications; it asks me to select them all.  
So sadly I'll do it manually. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, you did ask how to remove all applications.